# What’s the title of a vampire story where the vampire eats the heart of the sire to stop aging

Tags: story-identification, vampire

Back in the late 90s/early 00s, I read a story or short story within the Vampire genre. I feel like it was published long before that though.

It chronicled the life of a Victorian (I think) man who became a vampire. His wife was also turned (or he married a woman after she became a vampire, not sure). Throughout the story, the man ages regularly like a normal human. It starts when he is a young man.

Around the point of middle age, he learns that Vampires can stop aging if they eat the heart of their sire. However, since he and his wife were turned by the same vampire, only one of them can do so. His wife urges him to be the one.

The story ends with him talking to a woman (I think the whole story is him recounting the tale to her - much like interview with the vampire), and her discovering his wife, now vastly aged but still alive, whom he cares for and procures food (the insinuation being the woman is her next meal).

I feel like Tennyson or Byron were involved with the story, either as characters, or writers.